# Call a method of another class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, methods

I have a method called *methtod1* defined as:

```
Public Sub method1()
    For Each elem In Me.arrayElemWithLogkNull
        Console.WriteLine(elem)
    Next
End Sub
```

This method is in a class called `XMLClass`. So I have the `Main` class and, there, I want to call the method1 of XMLClass. How am I supposed to do that? I'm trying with this: `XMLClass.method1()`, but it's not working.

Comment: Classes are used to create instances of objects.  Since `method1` is not `Shared` it can only be invoked on an instance (`Dim myXML = New XmlClass`).

Comment: As a side advice, I would suggest to lear/review OO basics or else you'll be losing a lot of time just doing basic things like this...

Comment: as *another* side note, it is usually helpful to tell us the error, not just `but it throws me an error`.  In this case it is simple OOP 101 stuff, but usually the exact error is important to a good answer.

Comment: I have to review OOP basics, but I don't have much time. Of course I need it...thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize an object from this class to use it. It would be something like:

```
Dim myObject as XMLClass = new XMLClass()
myObject.method1()
```

Comment: I'm working with a code that is no mine, but there are some reference to methods of other classes and  they work. But not this one...that's weird.

Comment: They may be static methods, or namespace methods, or abstract classes. If XMLClass is a common class, it's necessary to initialize it in order to use its methods.

Comment: @daro. It is not weird. It's the difference between [Instance and Shared Methods](https://www.w3computing.com/vb2008/vb-instance-shared-methods/)